# I have WPF window that i want to Print on paper size **4inch by 6inch**

Tags: c#, wpf, printing

I have WPF window that i want to Print on paper size **4inch by 6inch**.

i dont understand where to set this size?? 
i am using window size to print but window size its not working.
my printer is not fixed paper size.
 this is my print code:

```
private void _print()
    {
        PrintDialog printDlg = new System.Windows.Controls.PrintDialog();
        //printDlg.ShowDialog();
        //get selected printer capabilities
        System.Printing.PrintCapabilities capabilities = printDlg.PrintQueue.GetPrintCapabilities(printDlg.PrintTicket);

        //get scale of the print wrt to screen of WPF visual
        double scale = Math.Min(capabilities.PageImageableArea.ExtentWidth / this.ActualWidth, capabilities.PageImageableArea.ExtentHeight /
                       this.ActualHeight);

        //Transform the Visual to scale
        this.LayoutTransform = new ScaleTransform(scale, scale);

        //get the size of the printer page
        Size sz = new Size(this.ActualWidth, this.ActualHeight);

        //update the layout of the visual to the printer page size.
        this.Measure(sz);
        this.Arrange(new Rect(new Point(capabilities.PageImageableArea.OriginWidth,  capabilities.PageImageableArea.OriginHeight), sz));

        //now print the visual to printer to fit on the one page.
        printDlg.PrintVisual(this, "Print Page");
    }
```

Comment: try setting `printDlg.PrintTicket.PageMediaSize`

Comment: @nit : But how to set page in inches? i have window size  Height="490" Width="410".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In WPF `1 unit = 1/96 of inch`, so you can calculate your size in inches using this formula

you can set `printDlg.PrintTicket.PageMediaSize` to the size of the Paper and then transform your window to print in that area as below:

```
 private void _print()
 {
      PrintDialog printDlg = new System.Windows.Controls.PrintDialog();

       PrintTicket pt = printDlg.PrintTicket;
       Double printableWidth = pt.PageMediaSize.Width.Value;
       Double printableHeight = pt.PageMediaSize.Height.Value;

       Double xScale = (printableWidth - xMargin * 2) / printableWidth;
       Double yScale = (printableHeight - yMargin * 2) / printableHeight;


        this.Transform = new MatrixTransform(xScale, 0, 0, yScale, xMargin, yMargin);


    //now print the visual to printer to fit on the one page.
     printDlg.PrintVisual(this, "Print Page");
}
```

Comment: Transform is not available for Window.

Comment: i gave the general example where you can Transform the containervisual to scale.. you can use layouttranform in your case

Comment: i tried this  this.LayoutTransform= new MatrixTransform(xScale, 0, 0, yScale, xMargin, yMargin); not working :(

Comment: Nice and succinct, but you kind of glossed over how you get the `xMargin` and `yMargin` values.

Comment: hi @JimMischel, these are just the horizontal and vertical margins you want to give to your page. If you want 1 inch margin on all sides then xMargin and yMargin will be 96.

Answer (score 0):

You can also adjust the Visual with respect to the paper size. This code adjusts the image to 4x6 inch paper.

```
        var photo = new BitmapImage();
        photo.BeginInit();
        photo.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
        photo.UriSource = new Uri(photoPath);
        photo.EndInit();

        bool isPortrait = photo.Width < photo.Height;
        if (isPortrait)
        {
            var transformedPhoto = new BitmapImage();
            transformedPhoto.BeginInit();
            transformedPhoto.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
            transformedPhoto.UriSource = new Uri(photoPath);
            transformedPhoto.Rotation = Rotation.Rotate270;
            transformedPhoto.EndInit();

            photo = transformedPhoto;
        }

        int width = 6;
        int height = 4;

        double photoScale = Math.Max(photo.Width / (96 * width), photo.Height / (96 * height));

        var vis = new DrawingVisual();
        var dc = vis.RenderOpen();

        dc.DrawImage(photo, new Rect
        {
            Width = photo.Width / photoScale,
            Height = photo.Height / photoScale
        });

        dc.Close();

        var pdialog = new PrintDialog();
        pdialog.PrintTicket.PageOrientation = PageOrientation.Landscape;
        pdialog.PrintTicket.PageBorderless = PageBorderless.Borderless;

        pdialog.PrintTicket.PageMediaSize = new PageMediaSize(PageMediaSizeName.NorthAmerica4x6);
        pdialog.PrintTicket.Duplexing = Duplexing.OneSided;
        pdialog.PrintTicket.CopyCount = 1;
        pdialog.PrintTicket.OutputQuality = OutputQuality.Photographic;
        pdialog.PrintTicket.PageMediaType = PageMediaType.Photographic;

        pdialog.PrintQueue = new PrintQueue(new PrintServer(), PrinterName);
        pdialog.PrintVisual(vis, "My Visual");
```